# Is it possible to lock the mouse to one screen?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, mouse

I have a dual-screen setup, but it bogs me that whenever I play a 3d game and want to scroll somewhere by touching the edge of the screen with the cursor, it moves to the next screen.

The (relatively) impractical solution: Disable one screen while playing. Disadvantages:

- No use of screen while disabled
- Icons on desktop get rearranged every time I do this

It would be Ideal that if I Alt-Tab out ouf the game the lock would be disabled.

BTW: I'm on Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[WMC](http://veeteesoftware.blogspot.com/2008/11/wmc-1233.html)** is an extended version of Warcraft III Mouse Capture.
It allows you to **lock the mouse within a specified window** (not just limited to Warcraft III).

The primary use of this program is to have a game (in window mode) on one monitor and applications such as IM and internet browser on another.
Without WMC if you move your mouse to the edge of the screen while playing your game, your mouse will just leave the game. You wont be able to aim!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://ddmm.sourceforge.net/ (just coded - opensource - could be improved)

Answer (score 0):

[Lock Mouse Onto Monitor](http://www.murgee.com/MurGeeMon/monitor-control/lock-mouse/) is supposed to do that with a hotkey, although not much info is available.

Answer (score 0):

I made this for full-screen games specifically:

https://github.com/CyberShadow/AutoMouseLock

It will automatically lock the mouse to one monitor as long as the active program is running in full-screen.