# Lock the mouse cursor to one screen in Linux / Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, cursor, accessibility

This question has already been asked, but for Windows: [Is it possible to lock the mouse to one screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/50726/is-it-possible-to-lock-the-mouse-to-one-screen)

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with 2 screens with different resolution.
Getting the mouse cursor moving accidentally from one screen to another is really annoying.

Is it possible to temporarily lock the mouse to one screen, and possibly releasing it with a shortcut ?

Comment: Does http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=903415#post9643088 help at all?

Comment: One other option is to add a bumper... you can set it up so the mouse will only switches if it goes a certain number of pixels past the edge of the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working! Better than in Windows !!

The trick is to separate the 2 screen by a virtual space in xorg.conf , then use a tool called mouse-switchscreen to "jump" between the screens.

My config: Ubuntu 10.04 x64, ATI Mobility RadeonHD , ATI Catalyst Control Center correctly installed, screens in mode "Single Display Desktop" (each screen has it's own Desktop)

These are the steps that I made:

1. Download [dualscreen-mouse-utils](http://dsp.mcbf.net/releases/dualscreen-mouse-utils-0.5.tar.gz) from http://digamma.cs.unm.edu/trac.dmohr/wiki/DualscreenMouseUtils
2. Decompress the package, in terminal type: *make* , you may need to xorg-dev package (in Ubuntu: *sudo apt-get install xorg-dev* )
3. Copy the mouse-switchscreen binary to folder included in PATH (I used /usr/bin)
4. Start gconf-editor (Alt-F2), in apps\metacity\keybinding_commands choose an empty command, and add: ***mouse-switchscreen -f 1***
5. In gconf-editor apps\metacity\global_keybindings choose the same number for run_command_n and add a shortcut of your choice, personnally I entered: ***< Super>Tab*** =Win+Tab (without space before Super)
6. If everything is working, Edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf (better make a backup before), in the "ServerLayout" section, change the position of a screen to make the two separate. ONE pixel is enough :D

You can now *sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart* and enjoy. Of course, Win+Tab to switch the screen. You can also try mouse-wrapscreen, *mouse-wrapscreen -h* for more info.

All credits goes to: David Antliff & David Mohr for mouse-switchscreen, and the Linux community for the infos.

Comment: if you get an undefined reference error during compile, add `LDLIBS=-lX11` to the [Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8998188/33499).

Comment: jesus this looks complicated for something so simple

Comment: The download link for dualscreen-mouse-utils is now dead.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't too much of a fix as it is an annoyance minimizer, but in System->Preferences->Monitors, drag the 2nd monitor to the edge so that they only touch corners. Theoretically, that means it'll only transfer over if you pull the mouse into a corner.
On the Gentoo Wiki, they [posted](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/HOWTO_Dual_Monitors#Mouse_Jail:_How_to_lock_your_mouse_in_the_monitor) a small program that might work also.
I bade you luck.

Comment: Excellent! No need to download anything. This is working like a charm in Ubuntu 12.04. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for a game or other full-screen application, I've [added](https://github.com/CyberShadow/hax11/commit/54a07fbca6fabf46b16a8e7fbe090004454dfb52) an experimental option to hax11 to grab and confine the mouse cursor whenever the program's window receives focus. I've been using it with [the Dolphin emulator](https://dolphin-emu.org/), and it's been working pretty well.

https://github.com/CyberShadow/hax11