# Can I create a barrier between monitors in a dual monitor setup?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

We have a Windows 7 laptop that is hooked up to a projector for running slides. I really want to be able to put a barrier between the laptop's display and the projector (which acts as a second display) so that you can't move the cursor to the projector screen. Is this possible?

Comment: Also See: [Is it possible to lock the mouse to one screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/50726/is-it-possible-to-lock-the-mouse-to-one-screen)

Answer (score 4):

The [Dual Display Mouse Manager](http://snoofler.users.sourceforge.net/) utility allows you to slow down the mouse as it nears the edge of the screen - enabling you to better aim for what you want.

However, it has an additional feature that stops the mouse traversing from one screen to the next, unless <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is held down.  This would give you the barrier you want.

Comment: Looks like that will work for what I need. Thanks! However, I can't accept your answer yet, as I have to try it out on the computer (which I won't be running 'til next Sunday). So, hang in there; I haven't forgotten about your answer, and I will be back next week.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dual Monitor Tools](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/) utility allows [control movement of cursor between monitors](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/dmt_cursor.html). The cursor can be locked to a monitor or made sticky, so extra effort is required to move it between monitors.

It's free and open source, last updated in 2018, works on XP, Vista, Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10.